# How do you statistically compare breathing rates?

Tags: spss, multiple-comparisons

I have data containing breathing rates per minute of whales before, during, and after a test. I am a beginner in biological statistics and I am looking for the best way to compare these breathing rates, preferably using SPSS.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your data? How many observations? What is the purpose of the comparison? What aspect of the breathing rates do you want to compare? means? medians ? variances? ...

Comment: What information do you have per whale? One value per time point? Or multiple values?

Comment: There is one whale per trial. I have the number of breaths the whale took per surfacing in 30 minutes of observation. For example I have: 
Surface 1: 4 breaths in 00:00:54
Surface 2: 3 breaths in 00:01:27
and so on, then I can calculate an average breathing rate per minute.
I would like to compare the breathing rates of this individual for the "before test", "during test" and "after test"

Comment: Interesting. How are you calculating the "average breathing rate per minute"? Is it the total number of breaths divided by the total surfacing time?

Comment: I calculated the breathing rate by cross-multiplying. So for example 27 breaths observed / 938 seconds of surface time = X/60seconds. Average breathing rate = 1.727 breaths/60seconds